# How to make tun0 appear after openvpn installation without rebooting?

Tags: systemd, openvpn

I am installing openvpn on Ubuntu 18.04. The installation and setup goes smoothly. I start the systemd service and it succeeds. But, there is no tun0 interface in `ip a`.

If I reboot, then tun0 is there.

I tried `modprobe tun` before rebooting but that didn't change anything.

What does tun0 need to appear without a reboot?

Comment: Enabling and starting a service is not the same. All enabling does is making sure the service is started on every boot. Just start the service (replace "enable" with "start") and tun0 should appear.

Comment: I start the service, I edited the post.

Comment: Please post more information to allow us to troubleshoot this. For instance, output of `systemctl status openvpn.service` (or whatever the exact service name you're starting is), perhaps some lines from `journalctl -e` that you think might be relevant, snippets from `ip a`, `lsmod`, etc. You need to provide more information in your question to get an useful answer to it. Thanks!

Comment: To add to what @FilipeBrandenburger said: There's no way the start of the service is successful if tun0 doesn't appear.